# Repository created by Octokit doesn't appear on website

Tags: c#, .net, github, octokit.net

I cannot open repository created via Octokit from Github web browser (using standard url `github.com/user/repo-name`)

But what works is url `github.com/user/repo-name.git`

Additionally, Github shows this message on the page:

> Cannot retrieve the latest commit at this time.

I assume that it might be some problems in `.git` configuration files by they looks pretty much the same as in repos I create in web browser.

What might be causing the problem?

I can clone this repo using `context.CloneUrl` which works just fine.

I'm creating a repository via Octokit, which works fine

```
var basicAuth = new Octokit.Credentials(Login, Password);
var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue(repoName)) {Credentials = basicAuth};

var repository = new NewRepository(repoName)
{
    AutoInit = false,
    Description = null,
    Private = false
};
var context = await client.Repository.Create(repository);
```

Additionally I'm using `LibGit2Sharp` to create and initialize local repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github was experiencing difficulties since last night check out https://status.github.com/messages . It might be back up now (10hrs later)